# Android InstrumentTest hangs until minimizing the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I just started to look into Android instrumentation tests but have some problems with getting my tests executed. Here is what I tried:

Using Android Studio and gradle, I created a simple test class within `src/instrumentTest/java/`. Here it is:

```
package at.example.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.view.View;
import at.example.activity.MainActivity;

public class BasicAppTestCase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity activity;

    public BasicAppTestCase() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testAppHomeButtonExists() {
        View homeButton = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        assertNotNull("Home button does not exist", homeButton);
    }
}
```

Next, I start the test using by right clicking on my project and selecting `Run 'All Tests'`. Android Studio executes `assembleDebug` and `assembleTest` tasks for my project, and installs both `apk` files onto my test device.

Afterwards, the app is successfully started on my test device. The `setUp()` method is getting executed (I checked this by putting a failing assert into the method as well as using `logcat`) and then the test execution hangs, showing `Running tests...` and `testAppHomeButtonExists` as being currently executed.

The test execution won't proceed until I change the activity state by minimizing the app pressing the home button or opening the app switcher. Then the test method `testAppHomeButtonExists` gets executed and (depending on the methods body) succeeds or fails. Again, I tested this behavior using assert calls and the `logcat` output.

**UPDATE:**

This is what the `TestRunner` is logging to my device's logcat stream:

```
11-11 15:34:59.750  24730-24748/at.example.activity I/TestRunner﹕ started: testAppHomeButtonExists(BasicAppTestCase)
```

Up until I stop the app nothing more is logged. After stopping the activity following is logged:

```
11-11 15:35:05.205  24730-24748/at.example.activity I/TestRunner﹕ finished: testAppHomeButtonExists(BasicAppTestCase)
11-11 15:35:05.205  24730-24748/at.example.activity I/TestRunner﹕ passed: testAppHomeButtonExists(BasicAppTestCase)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? What could cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, the test seems to run without problems when the device is locked (screen turned off).

Comment: I created a blank new project. This works fine. It seems to be something with my other's project configuration. Probably some, gradle  config stuff (flavors, built types, etc.). I will post once I have further information.

Comment: It seems flavors and build types do not produce this problem. I also eliminated Android Annotations from the suspects, as I created a copy of my affected activity that does not use it. Next suspect is the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem: I created an infinite invalidation loop inside one of my views `onDraw()` method. *A velociraptor should eat me for using old code without checking it first.* This is what the view's drawing method looked like:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Get the current location on screen in pixels (left = 0)
    int[] location = new int[2];
    this.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    // Translate the canvas for the same location as its current offset (resulting in a doubled shift).
    canvas.translate(location[0], 0);

    // Now draw the translated content.
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    this.invalidate();
}
```

The above drawing method created a "faked parallax effect" of the view's content. The problem was, that although this did not result in a ANR it caused the hosting `Activity` to never go idle causing my test's `getActivity()` method not to return as it's implementation waits for an idle activity (meaning the setup completed). The question [Android animation causing "Activity idle timeout for History Record" on start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084746/android-animation-causing-activity-idle-timeout-for-history-record-on-start-up) is a similar problem. My quick solution was to defer the `invalidate()` call to the parent ViewPager. Since my parallax effect needed only to be updated when the position of my page changed I am now using a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()` that updates child views as soon as they move.

This fixes the problem for me! My tests are running now and are fully functional!

Comment: I also documented that behavior on http://www.droidwok.net/android-development/infinite-invalidation-loops-render-your-code-untestable/. I hope this can help anybody who will run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking view like that u can try something like this :

```
public class BasicAppTestCase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity activity;
    private Button;
    public BasicAppTestCase() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
        button = (Button) activity
                .findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    }


    public final void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    public final void testFieldsOnScreen() {
        final Window window = tAes_Activity.getWindow();
        final View origin = window.getDecorView();
        assertOnScreen(origin, button);

    }
}
```

Comment: My tests wont execute at all, so your proposed changes don't do any difference. Nonetheless, I tried it. Here is what happened: The first test that **did not execute** was `testFieldsOnScreen`. After I minimized the app, the test was completed successfully **but** the app was not minimized. Afterwards, the second test `testPreconditions` was stuck again! After minimizing the app another time (!) the second test was executed. What's this strange behavior? Or is this even expected? Should test only execute with inactive devices?

Comment: hmmm it'll be struck'd b'coz it won't be getting proper reference...yes even i faced some problem.....you don't have to minimize it .what happens if u don't minimize are u getting ANR error??

Comment: No, the app is running properly. Just the tests won't be executed.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try another setup and look if I got any differences.

Comment: This is the id of the applications home button that is located in the top left corner (on the action bar). This button usually goes up one hierarchy level or toggles the navigation drawer.