# Cucumber-JVM Android - Testing Native applications using JUnit

Tags: android, junit, cucumber-jvm

I am having trouble testing native applications (such as Contacts and Settings) using Cucumber-JVM for Android with JUnit. Initially, I got the following message:

"Test run failed: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo???{com.test.contacts/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner???} from pid=673, uid=673 not allowed because package com.test.contacts does not have a signature matching the target com.android.contacts"

To solve this problem, I signed the test application with the same keys of the Contacts native android application (shared.x509.pem and shared.pk8) and I also added the following line to the AndroidManifest.xml file (as suggested in [How can I sign my application with the system signature key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557159/how-can-i-sign-my-application-with-the-system-signature-key)):

“android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shared"

This seemed to solve the problem.

However, after this change, I only manage to run the first test from a test suite. When the second test is running, it gets lost in the getActivity() method from the class ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, which my steps definitions class extends. More precisely, it doesn't get out of the mSync.wait() call in the method startActivitySync(Intent intent) from Instrumentation.java. The call to getActivity() calls launchActivityWithIntent(), from InstrumentationTestCase.java, which calls startActivitySync(Intent intent).

I found a similar issue on [Why does getActivity() block during JUnit test when custom ImageView calls startAnimation(Animation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860832/why-does-getactivity-block-during-junit-test-when-custom-imageview-calls-start), but the workaround described there doesn’t solve my problem.

My test application is really simple and it only checks the content of the buttons in the activity. I don’t have this problem if I use the same test application to test my own apps, only with native android applications such as Contacts and Settings.

Does anyone know something about this issue and could give me a light on how could I solve it?

Thanks in advance